# SQL - select the penultimate date

Tags: sql

I have a table that has an [ArchiveDate] column like this:

```
ArchiveDate
2014-10-06
2014-10-06
2014-10-06
2014-10-01
2014-10-01
2014-10-01
2014-10-01
2014-05-22
2014-05-22
```

I want to select the penultimate date, but when I use:

```
select max([ArchiveDate]) -1 'previousweek'
from [PipelineArchive]
```

I get 2014-10-05 (which doesn't exist in the column), rather than 2014-10-01.

I can't figure out how to code this to select the "last but one"; any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ArchiveDate ORDER BY ArchiveDate DESC LIMIT 2,1`, or whatever your db's equivalent of `limit` is.

Comment: @MarcB: Probably SQL-Server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to sort on `ArchiveDate` in descending order, skip one record, and take the next one. For example, in SQL Server 2012 you could do it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ArchiveDate]
FROM [PipelineArchive]
ORDER BY [ArchiveDate] DESC
OFFSET (1) ROWS FETCH NEXT (1) ROWS ONLY
```

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b27c/2)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct([ArchiveDate])
FROM   [PipelineArchive]
WHERE  [ArchiveDate] = (SELECT MAX([ArchiveDate]) AS second
                        FROM   [PipelineArchive]
                        WHERE  [ArchiveDate] < (SELECT MAX([ArchiveDate]) AS first
                                                FROM   [PipelineArchive])
                       )
```

The most recent date is:

```
SELECT MAX([ArchiveDate]) AS first FROM [PipelineArchive]
```

The maximum date less than that is:

```
(SELECT MAX([ArchiveDate]) AS second
 FROM   [PipelineArchive]
 WHERE  [ArchiveDate] < (SELECT MAX([ArchiveDate]) AS first
                         FROM   [PipelineArchive]))
```

PRO

- it's (quite) standard SQL

CON

- it isn't simple to generalize to the n-th date

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge but I also,on occasion,wanted to grab the nth last date where n=1 (last date), n=2(penultimate date) n=3(3rd last date).....n=n (oldest date)... I found the rank() partition by... did this fantastically well.... so by your example

```
;with CTE as(
select A,B,archivedate,rank() (Partition by A,B order by A,B,archivedate desc) as Nth_daterank)
select A,B,archivedate where Nth_daterank=2
```

(returns penultimate date) for A&B You can then substitute the 2 for n as desired.